# Curiously behaving IF block in Perl run on Windows

Tags: perl, debugging, if-statement, nested-loops, bioinformatics

**Background:**  I have a Perl script that I wrote to go through two files.  The basic point of the script is to identify overlaps between one list of coordinates, defining the beginnings and ends of randomly selected chromosomal segments, and a second list of coordinates, defining the beginnings and endings of actual gene transcripts.

The first input file contains three columns.  The first is for the chromosome number, and the second and third are the proximal and distal coordinates, in base pairs, of the randomly selected regions.  For eg,

```
chr1    1100349    2035647
chr1    47837656   736474584
.       .          .
.       .          .
.       .          .
```

The second input file contains four columns: chromosome number, proximal coordinate, distal coordinate, and the name of the gene.  For eg,

```
chr1    1588354    2283765    geneA
chr1    55943837   787653743    geneB
```

Here is a set of test files I used to start off with. **First set.**

```
chr1    1   10
chr1    5   10
chr1    5   15
chr1    14  15
chr1    100 101
chr1    11  17
```

**Second set.**

```
chr1    1   5   geneA
chr1    7   10  geneB
chr1    12  16  geneC
chr1    18  21  geneD
chr10   126602211   126609396   B4galnt1
```

The script reads off the first line from the first list, then reads through all the lines of the second list, and prints for me whether and how the first coordinate pair overlaps with the second coordinate pair (Is the first coordinate pair outside the second pair?  Is the first pair inside or overlapping with the second?)  Then, the script goes back and reads off the second line from the first list, and repeats the process.  The first file has 200,000 lines.  The second several thousand.  It is running now overnight.

**The problem:**  When the script determines the relationship between the first and second coordinate pairs, it prints out a line to an output file.  Not all these print statements *need* to be sent to output, so I tried to comment them out.  However, when I did this, none of the print statements sending information to the output file got printed.  Statements are printed to the screen, though, just not to the output file.  The script is running, but all the print to output statements are being used, so the output file is getting huge.  If the script would just print to output for only those coordinates that overlap, the output file would be very, very much smaller. At present, the output file is now 2,131,294 KB! And that's only up to chromosome 11.  There are eight more to go through, albeit smaller ones, but the file size is still going to expand greatly.

**Updated information:**  This is edited in after my original posting.  To be more precise, it is only when I comment out the  first `print $output "...";`  statement that is inside the loop (the very first statement is to print a header, and this is before the loop) that the script fails to print anything, even when all the others are left alone (not commented).

**In case it matters:** I wrote the script on my Mac, using Fraise, but I am running it on a PC, the script contained in a Notepad text file.

**Here's the script:**  Note:  there are many print statements in the file, many commented out.  The print statements of interest are those printing to the output file.  Those are the ones that, when one or more are commented out, wind up never sending information to the output file.  Those statements look like:

```
print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tinside\n";
```

The actual script:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl
use strict; use warnings;

#############
## findGenes_after_ASboot_v5.pl
#############

#############
#  After making a big list of randomly placed intervals,
#  this script uses RefGene.txt file and identifies the 
#  the gene symbols encompassed or overlapped by each random interval 
#############

unless(scalar @ARGV == 2) {
    # $0 name of the program being executed;
    print "\n usage: $0 filename containig your list of positions and a RefGene-type file \n\n"; 
    exit;
}

#for ( my $i = 0; $i < 25; $i++ ){
#     print "#########################################\n";
#}

open( my $positions, "<", $ARGV[0] ) or die;
open( my $RefGene,   "<", $ARGV[1] ) or die;

open( my $output, ">>", "output.txt") or die;

# print header
print $output "chr\tpos count\tpos1\tpos2\tchr\tref count\tref1\tref2\tname2\trelationship\n";

my $pos_count = 1;
my $ref_count = 1;

for my $position_line (<$positions>) {
    #print "$position_line";
    my @posline = split('\t', $position_line);
    #print "$posline[0]\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]";
    open( my $RefGene,   "<", $ARGV[1] ) or die;

    for my $ref (<$RefGene>){
        #print "\t$ref";    
        my @refline = split('\t', $ref);
        # print "\t$refline[0]\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]";
        chomp $posline[2];
        chomp $refline[3];     
        if ( $posline[0] eq $refline[0] ){
            #print "\tchr match\n";

            # am i entirely prox to a gene?
            if ( $posline[2] < $refline[1] ){
                #print "too proximal\n";
                print "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\ttoo proximal\n";

                #the following print statement is one I'd like to be able to comment out
                print $output "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\ttoo proximal\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next; 
            }

            # am i entirely distal to a gene?
            elsif ( $posline[1] > $refline[2] ){
                #print "too distal\n";
                print  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\ttoo distal\n";
                #the following print statement is one I'd like to be able to comment out
                print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\ttoo distal\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next; 
            }

            # am i completely inside a gene?
            elsif ( $posline[1] >= $refline[1] &&
                $posline[2] <= $refline[2]    ){
                #print "inside\n";
                print  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tinside\n";
                print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tinside\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next; 
            }

            # am i proximally overlapping?
            elsif ( $posline[1] < $refline[1] &&
                $posline[2] <= $refline[2]    ){
                #print "proximal overlap\n";
                print  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tproximal overlap\n";
                print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tproximal overlap\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next; 
            }
            # am i distally overlapping?
            elsif ( $posline[1] >= $refline[1] &&
                $posline[2] > $refline[2]    ){
                #print "distal overlap\n";
                print  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tdistal overlap\n";
                print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tdistal overlap\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next; 
            }

            else {
                #print "encompassing\n";
                print  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tencompassing\n";
                print $output  "$posline[0]\t$pos_count\t$posline[1]\t$posline[2]\t$refline[0]\t$ref_count\t$refline[1]\t$refline[2]\t$refline[3]\tencompassing\n";
                $ref_count++; 
                next;
            }       

        } # if a match with chr

        else {
            next;
        }

    } # for each reference
    $pos_count++;    
} # for each position
```

**Data Files:**

- http://www.filedropper.com/proxdistalpositionsofrandompositions
- http://www.filedropper.com/modifiedrefgene
- Some output: http://www.filedropper.com/output_17

Comment: Fun problem!  What can be different, about commenting them out?  1 idea Have you tried using a `print $output "..." if UltraVerbose;` and seeing if a flag "works" like you expect?  Couldn't see anything wrong from reading through it quickly

Comment: Using Ultraverbose isn't working. Get error saying it is not allowed when strict subs are in use (looking up what this means...)

Comment: Also, even when I delete that `print $output ` line (line 54, the first `print $output` statement inside the `for` loop`), i get the same problem--nothing prints to output.

Comment: I don't see why this would matter, but the only thing that I see obviously different about that first, within-loop `print $output` statement, is that it occurs with an `if` conditional statement, whereas the others are in `elsif` or `else` statements.

Comment: The warning you got for `... if UltraVerbose` is because you haven't defined any constant / subroutine named `UltraVerbose`.  Try adding e.g. `use constant UltraVerbose => 1;` to the top of the script.

Comment: Also, just to check, you *are* commenting out just the `print` statement and not the whole `if` block, right?

Comment: I am wanting to only comment out the `print $output ...` statement, not the whole `if` block.  I still need that counter in the `if` block to work (`ref_count++`).

Comment: Here's another odd thing.  So, when I comment out the `print $output...` inside the if block, and comment out the previous `print statement` which sends the same info to the screen, it seems to work.  It prints to the output, but the output is incorrect.

Comment: The output is incorrect.  It is as if the first `if` block is just ignored, and lines fulfilling its criteria are evaluated as if they are being read by the `else` block.  Something is wrong with the `if` block.

Comment: If it matters, when I press control + C to stop the script, sometimes I get a message saying the Perl interpreter has crashed.  I am using Windows machine.

Comment: Post sample input files somewhere? I tried creating input files from your example but the script gets errors. Starting to debug it but would be easier with real samples.

Comment: @GreatBigBore, I will do that, soon.  What is a convenient way for you?

Comment: @GreatBigBore, I added two practice files I used to make the script.  They are up above in the question box.

Comment: @ES55 Ok, I got it running. Does the sample data you've provided demonstrate the problem? I ask because I can't seem to reproduce what you've described. But I'm not sure which prints you're trying to remove, so I might not be fully recreating your conditions yet.

Comment: @ESS55 & Ilmari: yes, that's right, $UltraVerbose might have been clearer if you're not used to perl constants.  Actually a variable is better, as you can turn debug prints on/off as you go, without re-editting to comment in/out.

Comment: @ESS55 : Did the code work on Mac, with a data set?

Comment: Where can i post huge files where others might find them?

Comment: @GreatBigBore, I will make comments in the code above for the prints i would like to comment out and those that i don't.

Comment: Using your dataset and your code, it seems to run fine for me. Want to post some output somewhere? People often use pastebin. You could post your large files there too.

Comment: first file is here: http://www.filedropper.com/proxdistalpositionsofrandompositions         second file is here:http://www.filedropper.com/modifiedrefgene

Comment: I have a feeling that we're looking at a bug in the version of perl you're using, but I'll keep looking at it with you if you haven't figured out the problem yet. But some issues: (1) SO will soon require that we move this conversation to one of their private chat rooms. No problem there, just a heads up. (2) One of the files you posted is an xlsx file. Is that intentional? How is it to be used? (3) your script takes two arguments; which file should be the first and which the second? (4) Post some output that I can compare to. Maybe both the output you want and the output you see.

Comment: oh, it should have been a .txt file, which i saved from an excel file. sorry.   the first argument is the name of the first file (3 column file called proxdistalposition...., and the second the second file (4 column file) called modidiedrefgene..... I posted some output here:  http://www.filedropper.com/output_17.    I just let the script run for about 5 seconds.  This output is from when all the `print $output` lines are allowed to run.  When the  `print $output` statement that is located inside the `if` block is commented out, there is no output.  And thanks a lot!  It's really bugging me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential flaws in your code:

1. Always use `while` when processing a file instead of `for`.

   Whenever you use the latter, you're actually loading the entire file into memory versus just doing line by line processing.  If you're actually able to support doing that though, you should go ahead and load your smaller file entirely and just iterate on the lines.
2. Split on `"\t"` not on `'\t'`.

   The latter is almost certainly a bug, unless you really do use a 2 character delimiter for your data.

Anyway, I've cleaned up your code considerably.  Removing duplicated lines etc.  It's likely that a lot of these changes may either not work (as it's untested) or not be what you want.  However, if you go through the code, perhaps it will give you ideas at the very least:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#############
## findGenes_after_ASboot_v5.pl
#############

#############
#  After making a big list of randomly placed intervals,
#  this script uses RefGene.txt file and identifies the 
#  the gene symbols encompassed or overlapped by each random interval 
#############

die "\n usage: $0 filename containig your list of positions and a RefGene-type file \n\n"
    if @ARGV != 2;

open my $positions, "<", $ARGV[0];

# Cache file by key
my %refgenes;
open my $RefGene,   "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$RefGene>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split "\t";
    push @{$refgenes{$cols[0]}}, \@cols;
}

open my $output, ">>", "output.txt";

# print header
print $output "chr\tpos count\tpos1\tpos2\tchr\tref count\tref1\tref2\tname2\trelationship\n";

my $pos_count = 1;
my $ref_count = 1;

while (my $position_line = <$positions>) {
    chomp $position_line;
    my @posline = split "\t", $position_line;

    # Only iterate on matching refs
    for my $ref (@{ $refgenes{$posline[0]} }) {
        my @refline = @$ref;

        my $desc = join "\t", ($posline[0], $pos_count, @posline[1,2], $refline[0], $ref_count, @refline[1,2,3]);
        my $message = '';

        # am i entirely prox to a gene?
        if ( $posline[2] < $refline[1] ){
            $message = 'too proximal';

        # am i entirely distal to a gene?
        } elsif ( $posline[1] > $refline[2] ) {
            $message = 'too distal';

        # am i completely inside a gene?
        } elsif ( $posline[1] >= $refline[1] && $posline[2] <= $refline[2] ) {
            $message = 'inside';

        # am i proximally overlapping?
        } elsif ( $posline[1] < $refline[1] && $posline[2] <= $refline[2] ) {
            $message = 'proximal overlap';

        # am i distally overlapping?
        } elsif ( $posline[1] >= $refline[1] && $posline[2] > $refline[2] ) {
            $message = 'distal overlap';

        } else {
            $message = 'encompassing';
        }

        print "$desc\t$message\n";
        print $output "$desc\t$message\n";

        $ref_count++; 
    } # for each reference
    $pos_count++;
} # for each position
```